# React carbon pie chart shows percentage instead of actual values

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart, carbon-design-system

I am trying to use carbon pie chart to display some information.However when i pass the value as below the chart automatically changes them to percentage.I would like to show the actual values instead of percentages.I tried looking at the docs but could not find a prop to handle that. How would i do this?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { DonutChart } from "@carbon/charts-react";
import "@carbon/charts/styles.css";

const colors = {
java: "#FF0000",
javascript: "#00FF00",
"c++": "#0000FF"
};

const chartData = [
{
group: "java",
value: 300
},
{
group: "javascript",
value: 600
},
{
group: "c++",
value: 200
}
];

const demoDonutOptions = {
getFillColor: (field) => {
return colors[field];
},
height: "300px"
};

function App() {
return (
 <div className="App">
  <h3>React Donut chart with label</h3>
  <div>
    <DonutChart data={chartData} options={demoDonutOptions} />
  </div>
  </div>
);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Attached is an image to show the current output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To show value instead of %, add below code according to your example

```
const demoDonutOptions = {
getFillColor: (field) => {
return colors[field];
},
pie : {
  labels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: ((data) => data.value)
  }
},
height: "300px"
};
```